# rtmfp open source implementation or FMS with rtmfp hosting?

Tags: flash, flash-media-server, rtmfp

Is there an open source implementation of rtmfp?

Is there FMS hosting that support rtmfp?

What is the price of FMS4 enterprise?

Thanks

Comment: Actually RTMFP is overrated - I've tried a dev FMS4 version, less users were able to use it. Back to RTMP/RTMPT with Red5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hear about $50K US.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, the FMES pricing mentioned above is per cpu.  The rumor I've heard is 40-70k.

It appears there is a new kid on the block.  OpenRTMFP Cumulus:
https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus

It is written in c++.  In speaking with the dev, it appears it does work, but currently is unstable.  He said he could really use some help if anyone with the right skills is interested in it.

Comment: 40-70k? it's on amazon you pay per usage.

Comment: @Saad First, FMES on Amazon was announced on Dec 14, after my post.  Second, that doesn't change the price of an FMES in a traditional setting.

Comment: sorry. Have you heard anything about the aws with fms4?

Comment: @Saad Nothing that you can't easily find with a Google search for "Flash Media Enterprise Amazon Web Services".